# How to publish jmeter run results to TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have TFS 2017 installed on our server and JMeter performance tests which i want to run through non-gui mode on TFS build agent.

I can't find way how to publish jmeter results to TFS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no approved plugin for JMeter (at least none I could find) that incorporate your results into VSTS test results. You would need to dump your JMeter results locally, add a task that captures the output and puts it with the `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` path. You will then need to make sure that your final task is a `Publish Build Artifacts`. This will ensure that your JMeter results will get published as artifacts as part of the build.

Now the fun part, you obviously want to view the results so you are left with two options. The first is to create a web app that contacts VSTS via the [API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview), pulls the JMeter artifact and displays the results as desired. There may actually be

Last option is to create a [hub](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-hub) page for VSTS. This could query the build, get the JMeter artifacts and render them as desired.

These are the best options I could find for you at present. You can always request such a feature in the [VSTS User Voice Forum](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services).

Comment: Thank you for answer and you confirm my investigations. First option is not possible (at least i cant find API for this). Second option - I lost few weeks to do this but im not a front-end developer so it not my way.

Comment: I put the link to the API for VSTS in the solution. JMeter can generate an HTML that you can pull out of the artifacts and simply render.

Comment: @virusstorm Are my eyes lying to me, or I can  clearly see that the question was about TFS, and your answer proposes solutions with VSTS. From my understanding those are completely 2 different instances.

Comment: @TiredOfProgramming It depends on the version of TFS you are using. VSTS and TFS are actually the same code base since TFS 2015. The major difference is frequency of updates. TFS gets updated quarterly while VSTS gets update bi-weekly. In addition, not all of the features in VSTS are added to TFS in the quarterly update. Generally speaking, if you keep your TFS server up to date, a lot of what you can do in VSTS can be done in your TFS server.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any build-in tool to integrate the JMeter with TFS for now.

You can have a try for [Cloud-based Apache JMeter Load Test](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/cloud-based-apache-jmeter-load-test) task. However it's cloud based, and need Visual Studio Team Services account.

There are detailed reports and analysis tool when using could based jmeter test such as this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/getting-started/get-started-jmeter-test).

Please reference this article for detail steps : [Running Apache JMeter based load tests in the cloud – how to](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/02/27/running-apache-jmeter-based-load-tests-in-the-cloud-how-to/)

In your case, the simplest way is as *virusstorm* suggested using custom extensions to catch your test results and publish test results. If you are not familiar with this area, there are detail tutorials [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview). Moreover you could also ask help of some ALM company and team.